# Unanswered confusion

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

As a new user and therefore perhaps "fresh eyed" to the site, I found the following a bit confusing:

In the main menu Questions you find a sub entry called Unanswered.

But in main menu one also find "Unanswered" as it's own entry (and sub-menu "no answers").

Have a look at the image,

[image]

Trying a little forth and back I now realize the difference, but perhaps an improvement can be made here simply by choosing some other title (ie. Non-responded or unsolved... ).

Besides from that, excellent pages and site!

Comment: And I think there's a not-so-subtle but potentially confusing/contradictory difference between them: the unanswered accessed from All Questions lists questions with no answers, the other will list questions with answers but not an accepted one.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment That's mostly right. The second "unanswered" tab shows questions with no upvoted answers rather than just ones without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow now uses different terms for these two:

- "unanswered": questions that don't have upvoted answers.
- "no answers": questions that don't have *any* answers.

[image: unanswered and no answers]