# Do feature requests have to be formulated as questions?

Tags: support, meta

I just came up with a "feature request", but then spent ten minutes finding out what to do with it, because I was thinking of a statement "we should do X", not a question "should we do X?", and [this site is for questions not statements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

I found the [feature-request] tag, and sure-enough [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142438/review-beta-questions-by-tag) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148600/request-for-scroll-to-top-feature) [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148585/unanswered-confusion) ["questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148493/filter-flagging-history) there are formulated as suggestions and not questions.  So it seems that many people including myself think of feature requests as suggestions and not questions.

My explicit question is: "Do feature requests have to be formulated as questions?"

Comment: I don't mean to come across as a pain in the butt, but have you given a look to the other feature requests? It might help you to see what is the trend. :P

Comment: I think the question "what say you?" is implied with any feature request and answered with votes. As long as you make it clear what exactly you are requesting you can write it in any coherent form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do feature requests have to be formulated as questions?

Nope. You can formulate your request as it comes to you naturally.

Comment: That's not the answer I was expecting at all. I was thinking about the "not a real question" SO flag but I guess it doesn't exist on meta.

Comment: @Douglas but why would one want to shoe-horn a feature request into a question when it isn't one? Look at the existing feature requests - most of them aren't in question form. Meta doesn't always follow the SO format 100%

Comment: @Pekka Well... I'm new to StackExchange and I thought only questions were allowed. The button says "Ask Question" and the FAQ says "What kind of questions can I ask here?"

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: That might be a little confusing, but I guess there's no better term. Newcomers usually ask [support] questions on Meta, so renaming it might be even more confusing.

Comment: @Douglas feature requests and discussions are an exception from that rule. It's a very informal place in many ways.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: So are bug reports. Adding *CAN I HAZ FIX?* might make it a question, but it's neither necessary nor encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the post you're referring to, but I just posted a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148604/167534) tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). It is a question, not a request, but I tagged it as such because there is an *implicit* request in there.

So I guess the answer is, "it depends", as long as it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is always nice to phrase your feature request as a question in order to solicit community feedback, although certainly not a requirement.

For example, the feature request;

**We should rename our site to duck land.**

Can be rephrased to garner opinion;

**Should we rename our site to duck land?**

However, if the feature request is obvious (such as a borderline bug report) then forget about the opinion part.