# Should "Does everything have to be a question?" be added to the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, meta

Should "Does everything have to be a question?" be added to the FAQ?

Even though the button to start a new thread says "Ask Question" and the FAQ says "What kind of questions can I ask here?", not everything on meta is a question. For example, feature requests are often posted however is most natural, which may or may not be in question-form. See, e.g., this thread:
[Do feature requests have to be formulated as questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148609/do-feature-requests-have-to-be-formulated-as-questions)

There are also poor-quality posts flagged on Stack Overflow because they're not real questions.

I suggest that it would be helpful to point out in the FAQ:

1. That almost everything posted on Stack Overflow and meta should state
   a clear question, but
2. There are exceptions where it is acceptable to post
   non-questions, such as feature requests on meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Not a Real Question flag / close vote / close reason doesn't (necessarily) mean that the question isn't formulated as a question, but:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

A post formulated as a question can still be Not a Real Question, and the close reason might apply even for very high quality / interesting / popular questions, if they are, for example, overly broad.

Generally speaking it would be preferable for all questions to be formulated as questions, perhaps Meta [feature-requests] and [discussions] are an exception, but most of the times those can be formulated as questions as well. I personally wouldn't bother trying to turn them into questions though, if they don't naturally come out as questions, so be it.

As for your feature, I think the name of the button, "Ask Question", does a lot more to convey the information that questions should be questions than anything we could put in the FAQ. Not that many people actually read the FAQ, unfortunately, but *everyone* has seen that button and most of us have clicked it, at least once. Same for the "post your answer" button.